# char 5: error: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c++, while-loop, addition

I'm new to programming and I was trying to solve this question on LeetCode where:

Given a non-negative integer num, repeatedly add all its digits until the result has only one digit.
Input: 38
Output: 2
Explanation: The process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2.
Since 2 has only one digit, return it.

My Solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int addDigits(int num) {
        int sum =0,a =0;
        
        while(num!=0){
            a = num%10;
            sum = sum + a;
            num = num/10;          
        }
        
        if(sum>9){
            addDigits(sum);
        }else{
            return sum;
        }
        
    }
};
```

This code works fine with other compilers but gives errors when I try to run it on the IDE provided by LeetCode

Error:

```
Line 18: Char 5: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Please Suggest a way to overcome this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```cpp
addDigits(sum);
```

You're calling the function, but you're not doing anything with its return value. You have to actually return the value:

```cpp
return addDigits(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
int addDigits(int num) {
        int sum =0,a =0;
        
        while(num!=0){
            a = num%10;
            sum = sum + a;
            num = num/10;          
        }
        
        if(sum>9){
            addDigits(sum);
        }else{
            return sum;
        }
        
    }
```

You got an extra else there do it like this instead:

```
int addDigits(int num) {
        int sum =0,a =0;
        
        while(num!=0){
            a = num%10;
            sum = sum + a;
            num = num/10;          
        }
        
        if(sum>9){
            return addDigits(sum);
        }
        return sum;
        
    }
```